# Cant run two separate versions of Elasticsearch on the same machine

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I am trying to run two separate versions of Elasticsearch as follows

```
version 1.7.2

cluster.name: elastic172
http.port: 9200
transport.tcp.port: 9301
```

and

```
version 2.3.5

cluster.name: elastic235
http.port: 9201
transport.tcp.port: 9300
```

i keep rest of the settings as default. Version 1.7.2 starts up just fine

```
[2016-08-25 13:31:32,308][INFO ][node                     ] [Robert Hunter] version[1.7.2], pid[28186], build[e43676b/2015-09-14T09:49:53Z]
[2016-08-25 13:31:32,308][INFO ][node                     ] [Robert Hunter] initializing ...
[2016-08-25 13:31:32,370][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Robert Hunter] loaded [], sites []
[2016-08-25 13:31:32,425][INFO ][env                      ] [Robert Hunter] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/home (bluej670:/newhome/home)]], net usable_space [1.1tb], net total_space [3.6tb], types [nfs]
[2016-08-25 13:31:34,404][INFO ][node                     ] [Robert Hunter] initialized
[2016-08-25 13:31:34,404][INFO ][node                     ] [Robert Hunter] starting ...
[2016-08-25 13:31:34,465][INFO ][transport                ] [Robert Hunter] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9301]}, publish_address {inet[/192.168.2.105:9301]}
[2016-08-25 13:31:34,511][INFO ][discovery                ] [Robert Hunter] elastic172/RjoXxcRXQW-AZvJpYS7RMg
[2016-08-25 13:31:38,279][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Robert Hunter] new_master [Robert Hunter][RjoXxcRXQW-AZvJpYS7RMg][bluej335][inet[/192.168.2.105:9301]], reason: zen-disco-join (elected_as_master)
[2016-08-25 13:31:38,301][INFO ][http                     ] [Robert Hunter] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9200]}, publish_address {inet[/192.168.2.105:9200]}
[2016-08-25 13:31:38,301][INFO ][node                     ] [Robert Hunter] started
[2016-08-25 13:31:38,317][INFO ][gateway                  ] [Robert Hunter] recovered [0] indices into cluster_state
```

and i can test it using `curl`

Version 2.3.5 starts up as well, however it runs into some exception like

```
    [2016-08-25 13:33:23,596][WARN ][bootstrap                ] unable to install syscall filter: seccomp unavailable: CONFIG_SECCOMP not compiled into kernel, CONFIG_SECCOMP and CONFIG_SECCOMP_FILTER are needed
[2016-08-25 13:33:23,760][INFO ][node                     ] [Neuronne] version[2.3.5], pid[28287], build[90f439f/2016-07-27T10:36:52Z]
[2016-08-25 13:33:23,760][INFO ][node                     ] [Neuronne] initializing ...
[2016-08-25 13:33:24,318][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Neuronne] modules [reindex, lang-expression, lang-groovy], plugins [], sites []
[2016-08-25 13:33:24,340][INFO ][env                      ] [Neuronne] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/home (bluej670:/newhome/home)]], net usable_space [1.1tb], net total_space [3.6tb], spins? [possibly], types [nfs]
[2016-08-25 13:33:24,341][INFO ][env                      ] [Neuronne] heap size [989.8mb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
[2016-08-25 13:33:24,341][WARN ][env                      ] [Neuronne] max file descriptors [8192] for elasticsearch process likely too low, consider increasing to at least [65536]
[2016-08-25 13:33:25,767][INFO ][node                     ] [Neuronne] initialized
[2016-08-25 13:33:25,767][INFO ][node                     ] [Neuronne] starting ...
[2016-08-25 13:33:25,827][INFO ][transport                ] [Neuronne] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9300}, bound_addresses {[::1]:9300}, {127.0.0.1:9300}
[2016-08-25 13:33:25,831][INFO ][discovery                ] [Neuronne] elastic235/F3LQQNenSIKsm8zocG2muQ
[2016-08-25 13:33:25,958][WARN ][transport.netty          ] [Neuronne] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0x68b84cce, /127.0.0.1:43077 => /127.0.0.1:9301]], closing connection
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.handleException(MessageChannelHandler.java:207)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.handlerResponseError(MessageChannelHandler.java:202)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.messageReceived(MessageChannelHandler.java:136)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:462)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:443)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:303)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2016-08-25 13:33:25,965][WARN ][transport.netty          ] [Neuronne] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0x9dca84ed, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:48786 => /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9301]], closing connection
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.handleException(MessageChannelHandler.java:207)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.handlerResponseError(MessageChannelHandler.java:202)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.messageReceived(MessageChannelHandler.java:136)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:462)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:443)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:303)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2016-08-25 13:33:27,360][WARN ][transport.netty          ] [Neuronne] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0x953d2990, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:48792 => /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9301]], closing connection
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.handleException(MessageChannelHandler.java:207)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.handlerResponseError(MessageChannelHandler.java:202)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.messageReceived(MessageChannelHandler.java:136)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:462)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:443)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:303)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2016-08-25 13:33:27,360][WARN ][transport.netty          ] [Neuronne] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0xfcfdce32, /127.0.0.1:43084 => /127.0.0.1:9301]], closing connection
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.handleException(MessageChannelHandler.java:207)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.handlerResponseError(MessageChannelHandler.java:202)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.messageReceived(MessageChannelHandler.java:136)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:462)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:443)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:303)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2016-08-25 13:33:28,859][WARN ][transport.netty          ] [Neuronne] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0xf802d20e, /127.0.0.1:43092 => /127.0.0.1:9301]], closing connection
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.handleException(MessageChannelHandler.java:207)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.handlerResponseError(MessageChannelHandler.java:202)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.messageReceived(MessageChannelHandler.java:136)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:462)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:443)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:303)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2016-08-25 13:33:28,864][WARN ][transport.netty          ] [Neuronne] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0x472bca07, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:48801 => /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9301]], closing connection
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.handleException(MessageChannelHandler.java:207)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.handlerResponseError(MessageChannelHandler.java:202)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.messageReceived(MessageChannelHandler.java:136)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:462)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:443)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:303)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2016-08-25 13:33:30,358][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Neuronne] new_master {Neuronne}{F3LQQNenSIKsm8zocG2muQ}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}, reason: zen-disco-join(elected_as_master, [0] joins received)
[2016-08-25 13:33:30,381][INFO ][http                     ] [Neuronne] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9201}, bound_addresses {[::1]:9201}, {127.0.0.1:9201}
[2016-08-25 13:33:30,381][INFO ][node                     ] [Neuronne] started
[2016-08-25 13:33:30,394][INFO ][gateway                  ] [Neuronne] recovered [0] indices into cluster_state
```

but here is the result if i curl it

```
curl <myHostName>:9201
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

am i missing something in either yml?

Comment: Please check the logs of your not working instance under \elasticsearch-2.3.5\logs. Looks like your instance is already closed. Regards,
Atul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `network.bind_host: 0` to your 2.3.5 configuration and then use `curl 192.168.2.105:9201` to query it.

Comment: thanks, can i still use the hostname instead of ip ? also, i see that the cluster status is yellow, although i can query the data

Comment: I think you can use the hostname, not sure. Try it. The cluster is `yellow` most likely because it's only one node in the cluster and you created an index with the default config (5 primaries, 1 replica). A primary and a replica cannot be placed on the same node, so if you have a one node cluster the replicas will not be allocated. Which means a `yellow` cluster. But that's perfectly ok.

Comment: awesome! thanks. i was confused because es 1.7.2 shows cluster status as green.